# how to use like operation in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on a database with sqlite in an android app I want to get some data using a like clause

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from INTERESTS contactid LIKE '%=?%'", new String[]{id + ""});
```

Comment: Just for suggestion: Use Realm which is very easy to handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you really want to use the LIKE operator: `?` variables don't go in quoted literals. You can use `||` to concatenate variables and literals:

```
contactid LIKE `%` || ? || '%'
```

(Left out the `=` in the LIKE pattern as it seemed out of place.)

Assuming you actually want an exact match and not LIKE:

```
contactid = ?
```